# Half-image half-color responsive background

Tags: html, css

I'm making a responsive layout which has a max width limit. 
And I'm stuck at this specific part, where I'm trying to make a div with the left half as a background-image, and the other half a flat color.

I tried with ***:after***, but the content stays behind it =/

---

Here is the codepen:
http://codepen.io/Skelun/pen/KrkopL

**HTML**

```
<div class="full-width half-background" style="background-image:url('http://vwwgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stock-photo-64109767-three-generation-family-enjoying-a-summer-vacation-together_web_new.jpg')">
  <div class="site-width-limit">
    <div class="col-wrapper">
      <div class="col col-1-2">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="col col-1-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.full-width {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-background:after {
  background-color: #77AB6E;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
.site-width-limit {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-wrapper {display: block}
.col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  /* irrelevant */
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.col.col-1-2 {width: 48.31%}
.col-wrapper .col:last-child {margin-right: 0}

@media screen and (max-width:1160px) {
  .site-width {
    background: red;
    margin: 0 5%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

---

Help me, please. I have no idea of what to do.

Thank you!

Comment: You may use mix-blend-mode http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OXzvXB or an rgba() color http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/AXxyLE

Comment: Stick your background image on the left column div and your background colour on your right column div

Comment: use mix-blend-mode.

Answer (score 4):

**`<edit>`** if it is about to hide half of the bg, then a gradient will do :
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GqyxvX

```
background-image:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #77AB6E 50%), url('http://vwwgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stock-photo-64109767-three-generation-family-enjoying-a-summer-vacation-together_web_new.jpg');
/* note the behavior of the container within small screens. you may cure the layout via : */
width:100%;
display:table;
```

```css
.full-width {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.site-width-limit {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-wrapper {display: block}
.col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  /* irrelevant */
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.col.col-1-2 {width: 48.31%}
.col-wrapper .col:last-child {margin-right: 0}

@media screen and (max-width:1160px) {
  .site-width {
    background: red;
    margin: 0 5%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width half-background" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #77AB6E 50%), url('http://vwwgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stock-photo-64109767-three-generation-family-enjoying-a-summer-vacation-together_web_new.jpg');width:100%;display:table;">
  <div class="site-width-limit">
    <div class="col-wrapper">
      <div class="col col-1-2">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="col col-1-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**`<edit>`** if it is about to mix colors :

You may use [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

example: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OXzvXB

```css
.full-width {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-background:after {
  background-color: #77AB6E;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode:screen;
  pointer-events:none; /*allow to click/select throught */
}
.site-width-limit {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-wrapper {display: block}
.col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  /* irrelevant */
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.col.col-1-2 {width: 48.31%}
.col-wrapper .col:last-child {margin-right: 0}

@media screen and (max-width:1160px) {
  .site-width {
    background: red;
    margin: 0 5%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width half-background" style="background-image:url('http://vwwgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stock-photo-64109767-three-generation-family-enjoying-a-summer-vacation-together_web_new.jpg')">
  <div class="site-width-limit">
    <div class="col-wrapper">
      <div class="col col-1-2">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="col col-1-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or an rgba() color

example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/AXxyLE

```css
.full-width {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-background:after {
  background-color: rgba(119, 171, 110,0.5);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  pointer-events:none; /*allow to click/select throught */
}
.site-width-limit {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-wrapper {display: block}
.col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  /* irrelevant */
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.col.col-1-2 {width: 48.31%}
.col-wrapper .col:last-child {margin-right: 0}

@media screen and (max-width:1160px) {
  .site-width {
    background: red;
    margin: 0 5%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width half-background" style="background-image:url('http://vwwgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stock-photo-64109767-three-generation-family-enjoying-a-summer-vacation-together_web_new.jpg')">
  <div class="site-width-limit">
    <div class="col-wrapper">
      <div class="col col-1-2">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="col col-1-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I do this without a url and using a src?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a background-image *and* a background-color to your element, and then make the background-image take up only half the width of the element by specifying a background-position and a background-size. Something along these lines:

```
.half-background {
    background-image: url('http://vwwgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stock-photo-64109767-three-generation-family-enjoying-a-summer-vacation-together_web_new.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-color: #77AB6E;
}
```

Comment: This way, when resizing the window, the background doesn't fill the height.

Comment: Oh, right. In that case, try to add `background-size: cover` to your `.half-image` class.

Comment: ... the way it is set up in your codepen at this precise moment, anyway. :)